# How to bind super key to Ctrl+Shift using xmodmap?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

I have read the xmodmap documentation. I could only find information on how to bind one key to another.

How do I bind one modifier key to a combination of other modifier keys?

Can I do this using some other software (like autokey)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the end objective to have `Super+foo` mapping to `ctrl+shift+foo`?

Comment: Using xmodmap, no. But using XKB, I think so.

Comment: @terdon Yes....

Comment: @Gilles How so?

Answer (score 1):

In the `xkb_symbols` section of your custom layout, add the following:

`key <your key> {
  repeat= no,
  type= "ONE_LEVEL",
  symbols[Group1]= [ Hyper_L ],
  actions[group1]=[ SetMods(modifiers=Shift+Control) ]
};`

You can replace `<your key>` by `<LWIN>` or whatever you want.

For the choice of the symbol `Hyper_L`, it is the more convenient that I have found. It confuses less softwares than `NoSymbol` or `Control_L` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section on RedirectKey [here](http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/gram-action.html).

> This action allow to emulate a pressing of key with anothe scan-code (keycode). [...] Significant difference of this method (using action) is that besides the keycode itself **you can specify the set of modifiers** that will be included into the key event message instead of the current modifiers set.